# How to discover electrical wires?

Tags: measurement, wiring

An electrician told me that some companies has really expensive equipment to be able to map how the electrical wiring is structured behind walls and floors.

I wonder, how is this equipment made? What is used to discover the wiring? Does it have to run current through the wire to be discovered?

With this and some programming, I hope to maybe be able to make a similar one myself.

Comment: So let me think: A 3-D x-ray mapping machine that creates a virtual 3-D map of the entire house with all wiring shown!

Answer (score 4):

Basically there are three methods

you either detect the (50/60Hz) field around the wire

you use a form of metal detector

you 'inject' a high frequency signal into the wiring and detect its 'radio' signal using a cheap AM receiver (a ferrite rod will give good direction/localisation of signal)

[image]

Comment: Maybe good to notice is that this circuit has *no* galvanic separation from the mains supply, so it really requires a good understanding of how it works and its potential dangers. The circuit diagram doesn't state any safety properties of various components, which I would at least expect for C5 and C6.

Comment: I can't fault this answer but none of these methods seem to correspond with the "really expensive equipment" mentioned in the question. I believe you can buy good quality examples of equipment using these methods for less than the cost of a decent multimeter.

Comment: @RedGrittyBrick The "really expensive equipment" is almost definitely electrician-speak for "Don't try this by yourself, pay me to do it" :-D

Comment: @Anindo: That makes sense. Don't laugh, but I thought I was being extravagant when I bought an [Extech DVA30](https://www.google.com/search?q=extech+dva30#q=extech+dva30&tbm=shop)!

Comment: @RedGrittyBrick Yup, there you go: A really expensive 30 to 50 bucks! If the unions had their way, these would not be available to anyone not a member of the local electrician's guilds.

Comment: Well I could make it more expensive by adding a flashing LED and a designer label.

Comment: Good discussion, but I guess the price was pushed by the computer software which followed